# writing loops in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, gis, google-earth-engine

I am trying to write a loop to export multiple images in a time window. rather than doing them all at once.

here is the script I am currently using that works great at exporting one image at one.

the collection size is 287 images a day, and I just need them named FRP and then the number that was exported.

if anyone could help I would appreciate it very much.

below is the code I am currently using to export one Image at a time.

```
var USgeometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle({coords: [-122.15, 41.25, -121.25, 42], geodesic: false});

Map.centerObject(USgeometry, 10);

// This function clips images to the ROI feature collection

var clipToCol = function(image){
return image.clip(USgeometry);
};

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC')
.filterDate('2021-08-05', '2021-08-06').map(clipToCol);
var listOfImages = collection.toList(collection.size());

//this is where you change your image you want to select

var image = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0));

var power = image.select('Power');

Export.image.toDrive({
image:power,
description: "FRP0",
crs:'EPSG:3031',
scale:100,
region:USgeometry
});
```